# Why does my category page display "posted on..." when all I want it to do is display categories?

Tags: categories, templates

Refer to:
http://blog.studentlife.uiowa.edu/svp/categories/

I just used a blank category template. What can I add to/change the code to make it so that it doesn't put in the category page like it's a post? I only want it to list the categories than cut to the footer/sidebar.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing either a) what Theme you're using, or b) the markup of your category template file.

Comment: http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/

This theme (Blank from Chris Coyier)

Answer (score 1):

Open the archive.php file of the Blank theme and delete this code from the top.

```
            <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for the &#8216;<?php single_cat_title(); ?>&#8217; Category</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
            <h2>Posts Tagged &#8216;<?php single_tag_title(); ?>&#8217;</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
            <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
            <h2 class="pagetitle">Archive for <?php the_time('Y'); ?></h2>

        <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
            <h2 class="pagetitle">Author Archive</h2>

        <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
            <h2 class="pagetitle">Blog Archives</h2>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That "Posted On" bit is part of the `/inc/meta.php` template file, that is being included in `archive.php`.

You can:

1) Modify `/inc/meta.php`

2) Modify `archive.php` to remove this include

3) Add a `category.php`, based on `archive.php`, but omitting the include of `/inc/meta.php`

EDIT:

Conditional statement to exclude the category archives:

```
<?php if ( ! is_category() ) { 

     // we're not on a category archive; do something

} ?>
```

Try wrapping this around the `include()` for `/inc/meta.php`

Comment: i'm pretty new at wordpress (and all the php codes). what's a good if else statement i can use so that it uses "posted on" on every page except categories?